# convert a string with parenthesis to an integer- %d format: a number is required, not str'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to insert a formula into an excel column. The inputs to the formula do not necessarily come from one row. I have-

```
formula= '=B4-(28.471-0.0146*B4+0.0008*B4^2)+D2'
formulaRegex= re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)(\d{1,})')
cellCoordinatesR= formulaRegex.findall(formula) #find a Cap. Letter and a number 
rowIndex=[] #list of the row indexes i.e '4' in 'B4' and '2' in 'D2'

for group in cellCoordinatesR:
  rowIndex.append(group[1])
rowIndexFormat= '('+','.join(rowIndex)+')' # add parenthesis to rowIndex list
'(4,4,4,2)'

newFormula= formulaRegex.sub(r'\1%d',formula) %rowIndexFormat
```

Error:

> '%d format: a number is required, not str'

What I want:

```
newFormula= formulaRegex.sub(r'\1%d',formula) %(4,4,4,2)
```

What I currently have:

```
newFormula= formulaRegex.sub(r'\1%d',formula) %'(4,4,4,2)'
```

I found a way with this:

```
newFormula= formulaRegex.sub(r'\1%d',formula) %
(int(rowIndex[0]),int(rowIndex[1]), int(rowIndex[2]), int(rowIndex[3]))

'=B4-(28.471-0.0146*B4+0.0008*B4^2)+D2'
```

But it requires that I have `int(rowIndex[i])` as many times as necessary. How can I have `%d` in such a way that I don't have to type `int(rowIndex[i])` so many times?

Comment: why not `rowIndex=[int(group[1]) for group in cellCoordinatesR]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `int` to the items in the sequence rather than one at a time.

```
... % tuple(int(i) for i in rowIndex)
```

But, given that the problem is that you have integers in strings, why not just interpolate them as strings using the `%s` placeholder instead of `%d`?

Comment: Thanks. I used the %s  placeholder and ...%tuple(rowIndex)